# Building generated C++ gRPC client into a DLL causes a crash when making requests

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, vcpkg

I am trying to generate a gRPC client in C++, and have the generated client code built inside a Visual Studio 2015 DLL project. For some reason when building the generated gRPC client in a DLL a crash occrus when making a gRPC request, however building the generated gRPC client in a static lib does not.

I have a reproducible example that can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/grpcdlltest/code/ci/master/tree/). The example contains the server to run inside the `Dependencies\GreetServer` folder, and two C++ projects:

- `GrpcDllTestClient` contains a build event that uses `protoc.exe` to generate the client code from the proto file inside `Dependnecies\GreetServer`. The command runs of `protoc.exe` can be found inside the powershell scripts `GenerateGrpcClient.ps1`. The generated client code (.h and .cc files) are automatically included for build.
- `GrpcDllTestClientHarness` is an exe project that references `GrpcDllTestClient` and uses the generated gRPC client code exposed from `GrpcDllTestClient` to fire requests.

The example contains two Visual Studio build configurations. `Debug` builds the `GrpcDllTestClient` as a DLL, which is the configuration where the crash happens, `DebugAsLib` builds the client project as static lib, which doesn't cause the crash.

When the crash occurs, following is the call stack that I can see:

```
>   GrpcDllTestClientHarness.exe!gpr_atm_no_barrier_fetch_add(int * p, int delta) Line 101  C++
    GrpcDllTestClientHarness.exe!grpc_core::CallCombiner::SetNotifyOnCancel(grpc_closure * closure) Line 189    C++
    GrpcDllTestClientHarness.exe!grpc_call_unref(grpc_call * c) Line 604    C++
    GrpcDllTestClientHarness.exe!grpc_impl::ClientContext::~ClientContext() Line 70 C++
```

I have installed gRPC using `vcpkg` with the following options:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x86)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET v140)
```

The options make vcpkg build gRPC libraries as static libs, targeting the Visual Studio 2015 compiler.

Any idea why building the generated gRPC client inside a DLL causes a crash if the client is used from outside the DLL? I'm happy to go with the static lib options, but interested to know if someone came across the issue before, and if there is a workaround.

Comment: I did not understand this sentence `if the client is used from outside the DLL` what you mean by `outside` ?

Comment: @Landstalker - The generated C++ stub is built inside the DLL project, and exposed through a factory to any consumer of the DLL project. If you examine the provided example, the ClientFactory would be the place where the stub is exposed.